# Where to find Rules Files for different OWL and RDFS Profiles?

Tags: rdf, owl, rule-engine, reasoning, dotnetrdf

as I understand, you can replace specific Inference Engines for RDF, RDFS or different OWL Profiles by different Sets of Rules for a generic Rules Engine (Using dotNetRdf SimpleN3RulesReasoner). 
But I can hardly find these Rules Files, except for one for OWL_RL_Profile.n3 and even that seems to use a non-Standard Syntax with lots of Commas, which makes me doubt, here a sample:

{?s, ?p, ?o}    => {?s, owl:sameAs, ?s}, {?p, owl:sameAs, ?p}, {?o, owl:sameAs, ?o}     .   #eq-ref #eq-ref

Am I mistaken or can someone point me to an authoritative Set of Standard Rule Sets.

Comment: What is the problem with this syntax? Left-hand side is the premise containing a triple pattern, right-hand side the conclusion containing three triple patterns in your example. RDFS is supported by another class which is probably more optimised, thus, the N3RulesReasoner is not used: https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Inference%20and%20Reasoning

Comment: As for Syntax: the N3Reader complains aubout the extra Commas. As for the reasoner I would like to use a generic one to be able to add Rules in Addition to the RDFS Reasoning Rules.